# How can I write a Makefile to produce two executables from one source?

Tags: c, function, makefile, macros, gnu-make

I have two source files, `foo.c` and `bar.c`. I've got a Makefile to build them like so:

```
OBJ1 := foo.o
OBJ2 := bar.o
EXE1 := foo
EXE2 := bar

all: $(EXE1) $(EXE2)

$(EXE1): $(OBJ1)
    gcc $(OBJ1) -o $(EXE1)

$(EXE2): $(OBJ2)
    gcc $(OBJ2) -o $(EXE2)
```

Then I realized that `foo.c` and `bar.c` are identical except for one function. So I deleted `bar.c` and in `foo.c` I put `#if defined()`s around the function like so:

```
#if defined(FOO)
void function(int blah) { /* do what foo does */ }
#elif defined(BAR)
void function(int blah) { /* do what bar does */ }
#endif
```

How can I rewrite my Makefile to:

1. `#define FOO` in `foo.c`
2. Build `foo` from `foo.c`
3. `#define BAR` in `foo.c`
4. Build `bar` from `foo.c`

???

Comment: You can pass the defined symbols like `gcc -DFOO...` instead of defining them in the source code.

Comment: Consider using 3 source files: `common.c`, `foo.c`, `bar.c`.  The file `foo.c` contains the `foo` version of `function()`; the file `bar.c` contains the `bar` version of `function()`; and `common.c` contains everything else.  You'll also need a header to carry the common declarations used by the three source files, included by each of the source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GCC's `-D` option to define macros, and eliminate the object files:

```
SRC := foo.c
EXE1 := foo
EXE2 := bar

all: $(EXE1) $(EXE2)

$(EXE1):
        gcc -DFOO $(SRC) -o $(EXE1)

$(EXE2):
        gcc -DBAR $(SRC) -o $(EXE2)
```

Comment: You really should add a dependency on `$(SRC)` in both rules.

Comment: Note that POSIX requires the C compiler ([`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html)) to support `-Dmacro[=value]` notation, so it is essentially generic (give or take the notation used for Windows compilers with `\D` (or is it `/D` — I forget and don't much mind either way)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Meaning I should write `-DFOO` and `-DBAR` instead of `-D FOO` and `-D BAR`?

Comment: No; the `-D` option takes an argument of either form `macro` or `macro=value`.  The space between the `-D` and the `macro` is optional, though POSIX rules prefer it to be there.  Conventionally (as in, most frequently), there is no space, probably for legacy/historical reasons.  Similar comments apply to libraries with `-l m` vs `-lm` — the spaceless form is normally used, but both are supported.  The significance of my previous comment is that you said "GCC's `-D` option", and I'm saying it is essentially a universal option (like `-I`, `-c`, `-o`, `-L`, `-l` are too).